# Matching an optional substring in the middle of the string with a regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to create a regex for extracting title, subtitle and publisher. I was wondering how to making subtitle search optional.

My format is:

```
Title-(Subtitle)-[Publisher]
```

Where:

- Title – is a string I want to capture in the 1st capturing group.
- (Subtitle) – is an optional string surrounded by parenthesis I want to
  capture in the 2nd capturing group.
- [Publisher] – is a string surrounded by square brackets I want to capture in the 3rd capturing
  group.

For example:

```
Programming.in.Python.3-(A.Complete.Introduction.to.the.Python.Language)-[Addison-Wesley]
Learning.Python-[O'Reilly]
Flask.Web.Development-(Developing.Web.Applications.with.Python)-[O'Reilly]
```

Right now, I have a regex ([see online](http://regex101.com/r/qH4aB9)) that will capture the first and third one:

```
(.*)-\((.*)\)-\[(.*)\]
```

My problem is that I don't know how to construct a regex that will match also second line (Title in the 1st group, 2nd group should be empty and the 3rd group with Publisher) if it's doesn't have a subtitle enclosed in parenthesis. Can this be done in a single regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the second capture optional using `?`

```
(.*?)-(?:\((.*?)\)-)?\[(.*?)\]
       ^^^         ^^
```

Also I have replaced `.*` with `.*?` to avoid greedy.

Comment: This doesn't work unless you make the first ```*``` non-greedy.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy matching is a good thing because it allows more efficient regex execution.

To enjoy the performance benefits and maintain pattern logic, use negated character classes which contain the next expected delimiting characters.

```
([^-]*)-(?:\(([^)]*)\)-)?\[([^]]*)]
```

Breakdown: [Python Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6C1J5C/1)

```
(          #start capture group 1
  [^-]*    #match zero or more non-hyphen characters
)          #end capture group 1
-          #match literal hyphen
(?:        #start non-capturing group
  \(       #match literal opening parenthesis
  (        #start capture group 2
    [^)]*  #match zero or more non-closing-parentheses
  )        #end capture group 2
  \)       #match literal closing parenthesis
  -        #match literal hyphen
)          #end non-capturing group
?          #make non-capturing group optional (zero or one occurrence)
\[         #match literal opening brace
(          #start capture group 3
  [^]]*    #match zero or more non-closing brace characters (no escaping needed)
)          #close capture group 3
]          #match literal closing brace (no escaping needed)
```